# Adjusting vertical position of a dingbat font symbol

Tags: vertical-alignment, fontsize

At the end of brief sentence I inserted a dingbat font symbol to point to an area on the page to the right. Since the original size looked small, I enlarged the symbol by using font size control command as follows:

```
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{pifont}
...
... professional sites) \ \LARGE\ding{43}
```

However, that, along with enlarging the symbol, also results in the symbol raising up some and breaking the vertical alignment (please see picture below). What is the best (and/or easiest) way to fix this issue?

---

[image]

---

**UPDATE** (investigating the simple `\raisebox` solution's problem):

Here's my **MWE** for this scenario:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{pifont}

\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[shortcuts]{extdash}

\reversemarginpar

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,
  marginparwidth=30.5mm,
  marginparsep=1.5mm,
  margin=25mm,
  includemp]{geometry}

\setlength{\parindent}{0in}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% I wasn't sure, if I could omit 'fancyhdr'-related
% code for the MWE purposes, so included just in case
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfootoffset{\marginparsep+\marginparwidth}
\newlength{\footpageshift}
\setlength{\footpageshift}
{0.5\textwidth+0.5\marginparsep+0.5\marginparwidth-2in}
\lfoot{\hspace{\footpageshift}%
  \parbox{4in}{\, \hfill %
    \arabic{page} of \protect\pageref*{LastPage}
    \hfill \,}}

\usepackage{color,hyperref}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.3}
\hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,
  linkcolor=darkblue,urlcolor=darkblue,
  anchorcolor=darkblue,citecolor=darkblue}

\newcommand{\makeheading}[2][]%
{\hspace*{-\marginparsep minus \marginparwidth}%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep}%
    {\large \bfseries #2 \hfill #1}\\[-0.15\baselineskip]%
    \rule{\columnwidth}{2pt}%
  \end{minipage}}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\pagebreak[3]%
  \vspace{1.3\baselineskip}%
  \phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}%
  \noindent\llap{\scshape\smash{\parbox[t]{\marginparwidth}{\hyphenpenalty=10000\raggedright #1}}}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\par}

\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}

\providecommand*\emaillink[1]{\nolinkurl{#1}}
\providecommand*\email[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{\emaillink{#1}}}


\begin{document}

\makeheading{Aleksandr~L.~Blekh}

\section{Contact Information}

\newlength{\rcollength}\setlength{\rcollength}{1.85in}%
\newlength{\spacewidth}\setlength{\spacewidth}{20pt}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}@{}p{\spacewidth}@{}p{\rcollength}}%

  \parbox{\textwidth-\rcollength-\spacewidth}{%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}ll@{\quad}}
      \textit{Mobile:}& \texttt{+}1-111-111-1111 \\
      \textit{E-mail:}& \email{first.last@provider.com} \\
      \textit{Web:}& \href{http://www.aleksandrblekh.com}{www.aleksandrblekh.com} \\
      \\
      \textit{Profiles}& (on professional sites) \ 
      \raisebox{-1.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\LARGE\ding{43}}
    \end{tabular}
  }

  &
  % Uncomment to add a vertical bar in middle of contact information
  {\vrule width 0.5pt}
  \parbox[c][5\baselineskip]{\spacewidth}{} &

  % Non-snail-mail contact information
  \parbox{\rcollength}{%
    \href{http://linkedin.com/in/ablekh}{LinkedIn}\\
    \href{https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aleksandr_Blekh}{ResearchGate}\\
    \href{http://quora.com/Aleksandr-Blekh}{Quora}\\
    \href{http://stackexchange.com/users/3422261/aleksandr-blekh?tab=accounts}{StackExchange}\\
    \href{https://github.com/abnova}{GitHub}
  }

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

---

Here's the **result** (as you see, the hand is still misaligned):

[image]

Comment: Frankly, this issue is not a big deal - I can leave it as is. But, if there is a quick and easy way to fix the alignment, I would prefer to do it. Forgot to mention that "(on professional sites)" and the hand are inside a tabular environment (same cell).

Comment: Sorry, I think I might have used the wrong term - it seems to be _horizontal alignment_ that I am concerned about here. I will leave the question intact until people will confirm this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use

```
\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{...}
```

where you use a negative `<len>` that suits your needs. The `0pt` optional arguments remove any vertical height/depth when moving the element vertically.

Comment: I appreciate your help and fast reply. Do I understand correctly that LaTeX code for the hand symbol should go instead of the ellipsis?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Yes, and `<len>` should be positive/negative in order to move content upward/downward. For example, `\raisebox[0pt][0pt]{-.2\baselineskip}{\LARGE\ding{43}}`.

Comment: Great, thanks again. I will give it try. Hopefully, I will report success and will be happy to upvote and accept your answer. Appreciate your code snippet.

Comment: Hmm... I tried your example and I'm getting some errors: `Missing number, treated as zero. }` and `Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). }` and `package calc Error: '[' Invalid at this point. }`.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: Sorry, that should have been `\raisebox{<len>}[0pt][0pt]{...}`...

Comment: No problem, thank you. Giving it another try...

Comment: Tried again (with the right order of arguments) and the symbol is still not moving down. Perhaps, the fact that it is inside a cell of a tabular environment can explain it... Is my guess correct?

Comment: Sorry, to be more accurate, the text and symbol are located within tabular, which is inside of a `\parbox`, which is inside of another tabular. I tried to create an MWE, but the compilation was failing, hence my code snippet.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: That shouldn't matter. It's therefore best to provide the community with something that can reproduce the problem. Without it, it's difficult to conjure what's going on...

Comment: Sure, I will try again to create an MWE that is compilable. If I won't succeed in some reasonable time, I will just leave the code as is - it doesn't look too bad (this is for my resume and CV).

Comment: MWE is ready - please see UPDATE section in the question.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh: I see. The reason why using `\baselineskip` doesn't work is because you're in a `tabular`. For those situations you need to use `\normalbaselineskip`. Alternatively, use a fixed-length like `-10pt` or `-1ex`.

Comment: It appears that I was right that `tabular` was impacting your solution - it was mostly just a guess :-). I just tested your suggestion and indeed it works beautifully. I greatly appreciate your and @Heiko's help. In fact, while his solution is certainly more advanced and flexible, I will accept yours, as it is lightweight and plenty good for my modest purposes.

Comment: +1 for the comment about `\normalbaselineskip`.  I can't say how many times I have been frustrated by the redefinition of `\baselineskip` within `tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

The following example defines `\largehand`, the larger version of the hand pointing to the right. It assumes that the hand symbols in `pifont` are centered around the middle of the typical full glyph height, represented by the filled square (`\ding{110}`). This is needed to reduce the white depth, when the symbol is moved down. Then the symbol is moved down, that its height does not exceed the upper case letters of the current font (represented by `M`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{pifont}

\newcommand{\largehand}{}% error if \largehand is already defined
\DeclareRobustCommand*{\largehand}{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{M}%
    \sbox2{\LARGE\ding{110}}%
    \raisebox{\dimexpr\ht0-\height\relax}[\ht0]%
    [\dimexpr2\height+\depth-\ht0-\ht2\relax]{\LARGE\ding{43}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\dots\ professional sites) \ \largehand\ TeX.SX

% Show symbol bounding boxes
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}
\fbox{\largehand}\fbox{X}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Amazing (+1 and will likely accept, though I'd prefer a simpler solution)! Thank you so much for taking time to share such a comprehensive answer. And, of course, it seems to me like writing that macro is an overkill, but it's most likely my lack of enough expertise in LaTeX. I understand that you solution is more universal and flexible, but I am curious about why @Werner's nice and simple solution didn't work. I was working on my MWE, which almost compiles successfully, but then I saw your answer. Do you have any thoughts about the simple `\raisebox` solution's potential issues?

Comment: MWE is ready - please see UPDATE section in the question.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I am using `\raisebox` as well, even with all length parameters, which are automatically calculated. You can also use a simple `\raisebox` with pleasant values. With `\fbox` you can check the bounding box of the symbol, see my answer.

Comment: But why the simple use of `\raisebox` doesn't work in my MWE above?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh It's already answered by [Werner's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252053/adjusting-vertical-position-of-a-dingbat-font-symbol/252060?noredirect=1#comment601257_252055): Inside a `tabular` the length `\baselineskip` is zero (disabled). Therefore you are not moving anything.

Comment: Yes, I just saw and tested @Werner's solution and it works fine. I will accept his solution, as more simple and lightweight, but I greatly appreciate all your help as well.